# Nodejs and Mongoose wait till document is saved before callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, mongoose

The following function takes an aggregate cursor containing several arrays of user Ids so the users with the corresponding ids can be modified and then saved.

The issue I am having is getting the function to only return once all the users have been modified and saved. Currently it doesn't do that and when I attempt to access the users later on (literally after this function) the modifications haven't been permeated through.

This is the current code that does the modification (might be some strange async additions as I have been attempting 10s of different options with no success):

```
function updateUsers(dataArray, done) {


dataArray.eachAsync(
 function(data) {
  let userArray = data.users;     

  async.forEach(userArray, function(userId, callBack){       

    mongoose.model('User').findById(userId, function(err, user) {
      // User document modified         
      user.save(function(err, user){
        callBack();
      });        
    });
  });
},
function(err) {
  //Only come here once all the users have been modified and saved!
  if (err) {
    return done(err, false);
  }

  return done(err, true);
  } 
 );
}
```

The data that is passed is:

> dataArray: Aggregation cursor

Result for eachAsync e.g. data is:

```
{ _id: 'GroupValue',
users: 
 [ 5a0b2f5bcd0813adeac2435b,
   5a0b2f5bcd0813adeac24357,
   5a0b2f5bcd0813adeac24358 ] }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the return statement via the callback after every single iteration of the callback. Thus, you are returning userArray.length times.

If you just want to insert the data and don't want the function that's using it to know whether or not they were successful in inserting, you could just do the callback immediately before even iterating through the loop.

```
function updateUsers(dataArray, done) {


dataArray.eachAsync(
 function(data) {
  let userArray = data.users;     

  callBack();
  async.forEach(userArray, function(userId, callBack){       

    mongoose.model('User').findById(userId, function(err, user) {
      // User document modified         
      user.save(function(err, user){
        //do nothing
      });        
    });
  });
},
function(err) {
  //Only come here once all the users have been modified and saved!
  if (err) {
    return done(err, false);
  }

  return done(err, true);
  } 
 );
}
```

Otherwise, let's say you want to only callback specifically after the **last** iteration. One dirty way you could do this is do a temporary variable outside of the loop, and an if statement in the loop that executes on the last iteration.

For this implementation, you must assume the function will never pass a non-zero length array of users. Otherwise, it would never run a single iteration, and not terminate. (You would want to write an if length == 0 case)

```
function updateUsers(dataArray, done) {


dataArray.eachAsync(
 function(data) {
  let userArray = data.users;     
  let tempVar = 0;

  async.forEach(userArray, function(userId, callBack){       

    mongoose.model('User').findById(userId, function(err, user) {
      // User document modified         
      user.save(function(err, user){
        tempVar++;
        if(tempVar == userArray.length) {
          callBack(); 
        }
      });        
    });
  });
},
function(err) {
  //Only come here once all the users have been modified and saved!
  if (err) {
    return done(err, false);
  }

  return done(err, true);
  } 
 );
}
},
function(err) {
  //Only come here once all the users have been modified and saved!
  if (err) {
    return done(err, false);
  }

  return done(err, true);
  } 
 );
}
```